# How to use Applescript to create the same new file in all subfolders?

Tags: applescript

I am looking to create a .DS_Store file (Mac) in every folder and subfolder where one does not exist, and then to lock every .DS_Store file both newly written and already existing, and then to set the modification date of each folder to the most recent item inside it.

I've written the following code, which of course does not work. I'd appreciate some help getting this right.

```
set MyFolder to "Macintosh Backup:Design Photos"

tell application "Finder"
    set SubFolders to every folder of entire contents of MyFolder
    repeat with xFolder in SubFolders
        set myFile to path of xFolder & ":.DS_Store"
        if not (exists myFile) then
            make new file at xFolder with properties {name:".DS_Store"}
        end if
        set locked of myFile to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Basically the Finder has no idea of invisible files unless `AppleShowAllFiles` is set to true in the Finder pref file.

Comment: The thing is, it knows enough to throw up an error if the file's there. Should I just try to bypass that error, then? If so, what does this code need to make it all work?

Comment: What is the higher-level goal here? DS_Store files are an old and largely undocumented feature (they were originally introduced to store Finder data about folder settings). The Finder creates them every time a Folder gets opened for the first time, and modifies them when the folder GUI or contents are changed. I have no idea what's going to break if you try to lock them, but breakage seems likely. Maybe there's a different way to accomplish your goal?

Comment: P.s.: when responding to comments, you should include an 'at' tag: e.g., @macuseronline. This will notify the other person that you've responded.

Comment: Just to let you know the is no _space_ between **@** and **name**, e.g. @macuseronline

Comment: @TedWrigley for some ridiculous reason Apple's Finder always changes its modification date whenever the .DS_Store file updates. How or why Apple cannot figure out that the modification date should only account for visible files is beyond me but it's never going to be fixed. So the method that I use is to first lock the .DS_Store file so it cannot be changed and then reset the folder's modification date to the most recent file it contains. I haven't found any negative consequence from doing so, but admittedly I am only doing this for archived folders where I am not adding new files.

Comment: @TedWrigley the goal is, therefore, to force the Finder to not update the modification date of a folder unless a visible file is actually changed.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley the goal is, therefore, to force the Finder to not update the modification date of a folder unless a visible file is actually changed.

Comment: I assume this means you have some workflow in which the modification date of a folder is important? Or is this purely because the behavior bugs you? I know that DS_Stores can be blocked on remote servers, but that doesn't seem to be your issue. I'll take a look at the script while I'm waiting for your response...

Comment: I use the modification dates of these folders for maintaining a log of the entries, so beyond the fact that it does bug me, I have a practical need to make sure the date doesn't change. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Are these folders restricted to a particular file-system area, or do you need a system-wide solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set myFolder to "Macintosh Backup:Design Photos"

tell application "Finder"
    set subFolders to every folder of entire contents of folder myFolder
    repeat with xFolder in subFolders
        try -- avoids error if no files exist
            set modificationDate to modification date of last item of ¬
                (sort (get files of xFolder) by modification date)
        end try
        set myFile to ((xFolder as text) & ".DS_Store") 
        if not (exists alias myFile) then
            set myFile to make new file at xFolder ¬
                with properties {name:".DS_Store"}
            set locked of myFile to true
        else
            set locked of alias myFile to true
        end if
        try -- avoids error if no files exist
            set modification date of xFolder to modificationDate
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```